# Set of permutations with no collectively fixed points

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

My roommate posed the following problem to me the other day:

> If you have M pens of the same brand, and each is a different color and is composed of N pieces of that same color, then how many ways can you reassemble all of the pens such that at least one pen is a solid color?

I wrote up the problem with a better explanation [here](https://steemit.com/math/@jackeown/kloster-s-pen-problem).

I think it's probably easier to find the number of ways to reassemble the pens with NONE of them in a solid color and then subtract that from the total.

I figured out that that's equivalent to asking, how can you choose $N-1$  permutations (not necessarily distinct) from $S_m$ such that there's no fixed point which is shared by all of them.

So for $N=2$, it's a derangement problem.
Do you know of a way to extend this for larger $N$?

---

Thanks,
John (Jack) McKeown

Comment: permutations without fixed points are derangements but there are M cases at very least.

Comment: I assume that each piece is numbered, and each pen must consist of exactly one of each piece? For example for N = 3 we can assume that the pen consists of an ink cartridge, a tip and a hull, and you can't form a pen using 3 hulls.

Comment: @orlp Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is this for m pens and n pieces per pen:
$$ f(m,n) = \sum_{j=0}^{m} (-1)^{m-j}\binom{m}{j}(j!)^n$$
I got this equation from here:
https://oeis.org/A135810

Bonus points for anyone who can explain this...possibly in terms of Möbius inversion?

Answer (score 1):

The $n$ on the right hand side should be an $n-1$ so that when there are $2$ parts to the pens we get back the formula for derangements.  The counting here is the principle of inclusion and exclusion, which is technically Möbius inversion on the Boolean lattice.